# Nginx reverse proxy doesn't handle redirects itself

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Google Spreadsheet that I'd like to serve as a CSV file but hide that it's served or generated by Google. So I published my spreadsheet and got [its public URL](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSUlrjaEVBi7EcU4hjRU23GQG5SHXByHq043i8kGAmPOQFfLMXd-p5NRiNyMLIx9psDqb9Qxs3Hcxen/pub?output=csv).

Then I set up an nginx as a reverse proxy with this URL:

```
server {
    location /sheet.csv {
        proxy_pass "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSUlrjaEVBi7EcU4hjRU23GQG5SHXByHq043i8kGAmPOQFfLMXd-p5NRiNyMLIx9psDqb9Qxs3Hcxen/pub?output=csv"; 
    }
}
```

But when I request it (`curl -vL http://127.0.0.1/sheet.csv`) the headings leak that the file is served from Google:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: https://doc-10-1c-sheets.googleusercontent.com/pub/mq6he3r7ig44qobar1fsg51390/2p33rp3pvj2smdslst6hihu19o/1678722040000/104267088953683837464/*/e@2PACX-1vSUlrjaEVBi7EcU4hjRU23GQG5SHXByHq043i8kGAmPOQFfLMXd-p5NRiNyMLIx9psDqb9Qxs3Hcxen?output=csv
```

I tried setting other proxy options (e.g., proxy_cache, `proxy_redirect off`, etc) but none of this helped.

For the sake of testing, I tried to use a different URL (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt) and it works (i.e., no StackOverflow host is leaked in headers except the cookies).

I guess, somehow I need to make nginx to handle redirects itself and not send them to client.

Comment: If you know another tool which can accomplish that, feel free to suggest it as well!

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: No, I haven't solved that.